# ZFS corrupted directory, but zpool doesn't detect anything wrong

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, zfs, corruption, diskmanagement

A directory on my FreeBSD 10.2 server somehow got hopelessly corrupted (wasn't ZFS supposed to prevent that?)

`ls` or any other command against it leads to current session getting frozen on the kernel level (even SIGKILL does nothing).

[image]

ZFS scrub finds no problems.

```
 # zpool status zroot
  pool: zroot
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h17m with 0 errors on Sun Dec 18 18:25:04 2016
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zroot       ONLINE       0     0     0
      gpt/zfs0  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

`smartctl` says everything is OK with the disk.

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   137   137   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       89
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   128   128   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       314 (Average 277)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       78
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   142   142   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       29
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       24681
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       78
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       306
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       306
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   171   171   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 20/46)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

Even `zdb` finds nothing wrong.

```
# zdb -c zroot

Traversing all blocks to verify metadata checksums and verify nothing leaked ...

loading space map for vdev 0 of 1, metaslab 44 of 116 ...
12.2G completed (  60MB/s) estimated time remaining: 0hr 00min 00sec        
    No leaks (block sum matches space maps exactly)

    bp count:          956750
    ganged count:           0
    bp logical:    43512090624      avg:  45479
    bp physical:   11620376064      avg:  12145     compression:   3.74
    bp allocated:  13143715840      avg:  13737     compression:   3.31
    bp deduped:             0    ref>1:      0   deduplication:   1.00
    SPA allocated: 13143715840     used:  1.32%

    additional, non-pointer bps of type 0:     123043
    Dittoed blocks on same vdev: 62618
```

The directory doesn't hold any important data, so I'd be fine if I could just delete it and get to the "clean" state.

One solution that comes to mind is to create a new ZFS pool, copy all the healthy data over, then delete the old one. But that feels very dangerous. What if system hangs and my server goes down?

Can you think of a way I can get rid of the corrupted directory without too much disruption?

Comment: You have only one disk! Go shopping and get another disk.

Comment: If ZFS and SMART both say that everything is OK, it is probably not the disk and not ZFS. Do you use NFS? Does the directory contain many files (you can tell from listing the parent directory)?

Comment: @MartinSugioarto no NFS. It's `node_modules`, so I presume so. This increasingly looks like a bug in ZFS.

Comment: https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2016-July/049740.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A directory on my FreeBSD 10.2 server somehow got hopelessly corrupted (wasn't ZFS supposed to prevent that?)

ZFS only detects errors from the disks, not from memory (ECC is responsible here) or your applications (because it does not know if you want to write garbage to your files or not).

Also, with only a single-disk vdev backing your pool, even if errors are found, they cannot be repaired. Add a second disk to enable this, otherwise you would have to delete affected files and restore them from backup.

> One solution that comes to mind is to create a new ZFS pool, copy all the healthy data over, then delete the old one. But that feels very dangerous. What if system hangs and my server goes down?

Then your server will most likely go down, restart and either continue without error, show the same errors or get some new errors. Nobody really knows, so I advise to focus on how to remove the error permanently:

Back up your data (as you should already have done, because even ZFS can kill your data with bugs or errors), reboot the server, check the logs for anything suspicious. Do it at a time where you can afford downtime. If you cannot afford downtime, you should have at least another machine that can take over, so think about your needs and strategy. If you find something that looks like a bug, try to reproduce it on a second machine (use `zfs send/recv` to copy the pool over).

> Can you think of a way I can get rid of the corrupted directory without too much disruption?

Use `zfs send` to copy the ZFS file system which holds this directory (worst case: the root file system aka the whole pool; best case: just this directory) and `zfs recv` piped (or piped over `ssh` or `netcat`) to copy a current snapshot over to another machine or backup medium, then delete the directory on the old machine as you usually would, and repopulate it from a known good backup or your applications (meaning re-install in most cases).

If anything goes wrong or you want to later investigate, you have the copied snapshot that holds all data, snapshots and metadata from this point in time.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. After some faffing around with a second HDD, I send/recv-d the entire `zroot` into a VM, and reconstituted server there.  That apparently cleared the error, but frankly, I couldn't trust ZFS after that. So while the VM was serving, I reinstalled the dedicated server from scratch, without ZFS. I'm now bringing everything back to the dedicated server.

Thanks for the help!